# Pandas read_csv: Ignore second header line

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have data files like this:

```
# comment
# comment
Header1;Header2
Unit1;Unit2
0;123
1;231
2;512
```

I'd like to read them with Pandas.read_csv using the line `Header1;Header2` as headers but ignoring `Unit1;Unit2`.

What I have so far is

```
pd.read_csv(datafile, sep=';', comment='#', header=[0,1])
```

which does almost what I want, except that it creates a multiheader from both header lines:

```
  Header1 Header2
    Unit1   Unit2
0       0     123
1       1     231
2       2     512
```

How can I tell Pandas to take only the first line as header?

edit:
This is my desired output:

```
  Header1 Header2
0       0     123
1       1     231
2       2     512
```

Comment: Can't you just do `pd.read_csv(datafile, sep=';', comment='#', header=[0,).drop(0)`?

Comment: @EdChum This seems to remove the first data line (the one that starts with 0), but I'd like to get rid of the line with Unit1, Unit2

Answer (score 7):

You can pass `[3]` as arg to `skiprows`:

```
In [100]:
t="""# comment
# comment
Header1;Header2
Unit1;Unit2
0;123
1;231
2;512"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=';', comment='#', skiprows=[3])
df

Out[100]:
   Header1  Header2
0        0      123
1        1      231
2        2      512
```

**EDIT**

For your initial issue, you can read your csv as you've alread done and then overwrite the columns with `droplevel`:

```
In [4]:
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)
df

Out[4]:
   Header1  Header2
0        0      123
1        1      231
2        2      512
```

Comment: Your answer is correct (as usual). In the past (I don't remember in which version of pandas), I've had problems with malformed CSVs where this kind of stuff didn't always work. It seemed like somehow pd was first parsing (or attempting to), only then skipping, and I had to resort to the inelegant technique in my answer. Of course, the versions keep changing, so I don't know if it's still necessary at all.

Comment: @AmiTavory I guess what is a little confusing here but makes sense is that you have to know that the 4th line is the one to skip which is why I prefer just `drop`ing the first row, however, I suspect that if you did it that way it may mess up the `dtype` of the df as it would introduce mixed `dtype` for that column, indeed that is what happens even after dropping the dtype is `object`

Comment: This works in this specific case - thank you! However, I still have to find another solution because the number of comment lines (starting with #) is not fixed.

Comment: Is the second header always present and in that form?

Comment: I think you can just overwrite the columns with the returned output from `droplevel`

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise, you can tell pandas to use the first row as the column names with the option `header=2`,
but then to skip the second row with the option `skiprows =[3]`,
which gives the following command :

```
>>pd.read_csv(datafile, sep=';', comment='#', header=0, skiprows=[1])  

   Header1  Header2
0        0      123
1        1      231
2        2      512
```